# Evento de collapse en Boostrap no accede a variables globales vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, vue.js

En la documentación de **Bootstrap 4.3** acerca de los eventos de **javascript** de los collapse muestra aquello:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something...
})
```

El problema es cuando quiero introducir información a una variable global de **vuejs** (component) dentro de la función.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                dataattendancestudent: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ejemplo(){
                $('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                     this.dataattendancestudent = 'alguna cosa';
                })
                console.log(this.dataattendancestudent); // undefined
             },
        }
</script>
```

Algo estaré haciendo mal (lo mas posible) para que me puedan orientar por favor, ya que he buscado en varios sitios web alguna referencia, pero nada.

saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una función de flecha ()=> en lugar de la palabra Function.

```
       $('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', ()=> {
             this.dataattendancestudent = 'alguna cosa';
        })
```